# How to join columns of two files in unix system

Tags: linux, shell

I have 2 files, each file has one column with multiple rows and the rows of each file are the same. How can I join the 2 files' columns together so that the final result file has two columns coming from file1 and file2?

For example, file1 is:

```
1
2
3
```

and file2 is:

```
a
b
c
```

and the expected output is:

```
1   a
2   b
3   c
```

Comment: My telepathy is a little rusty.  Can you show us examples of the two files, and a sample of the output you're looking to generate?

Comment: for example, file1 : 1\n2\n3\n   file2:a\nb\nc\n  , here \n is the CLRF

Comment: This sort of stuff should definitely be added to your question, not left in comments.  If you like, you can click the (edit link under your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12361977/edit) to get it in the right place.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Just use the paste command. Use it like this : `paste file1 file2`